# MySQL: Table name with UTF characters

Tags: mysql, unicode, encoding, utf-8, utf

I'm having a hard time creating a table in MySQL with UTF characters. I am completely lost on how to solve this one.

There's only two special characters in this particular table name:

- 1F4D2  LEDGER (http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F300.pdf)
- 274E ❎ NEGATIVE SQUARED CROSS MARK (http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2700.pdf)

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE `_❎` (id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT);
```

Message:

```
Invalid utf8 character string: '_❎'
```

This works, however:

```
SELECT _utf8'_❎'
```

Comment: What is the default encoding of your database? I bet `utf8_general_ci` won't cover that level of utf8

Comment: I see... I tried this:                     

    `CREATE DATABASE \`test_utf8\` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET \`utf8\`;`
    `USE \`test_utf8\`;`
    `CREATE TABLE \`_❎\` (id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using MySQL 5.5.3 or later I would set your character set to [utf8mb4](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html)

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the following page:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html

The problematic char is `1F4D2`, as the documentation states:

> Permitted characters in quoted identifiers include the full Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), except U+0000:
>
> ASCII: U+0001 .. U+007F
>
> Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF
>
> **ASCII NUL (U+0000) and supplementary characters (U+10000 and higher) are not permitted in quoted or unquoted identifiers**.

Comment: That's why utf8mb4 is the ideal answer here. It DOES support supplemental characters.

Comment: You can't use it for table name, since mysql stores identifiers using utf-8 and doesn't support supplementary characters for identifiers.